# Why does Vue.js have events and not just function props?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've seen [this blog post](https://medium.com/js-dojo/passing-functions-as-props-an-anti-pattern-in-vue-js-b542fc0cf5d) claim that using properties to pass callbacks is an anti-pattern in Vue.js

But it doesn't make sense to me. The problems mentioned:

> By passing functions down as props, you are linking both parent child components together with two-way data binding

These events are mechanically doing the exact same thing as a callback prop, so this doesn't add up.

> As the application grows larger in size and other developers come on board, they will look at the child component code and have to figure out which callback function prop it is and where it is from.

You can replace the word `callback function prop` with `event` and you get the same problem.

Using functions instead of string names would avoid the kebab-case issue. Also, function-props would allow typescript to verify the function signatures are compatible. I think events should be removed and replaced entirely with callback props. The only downside I see for removing the events tech is a namespacing issue for events like `click` that you might want as properties.

What are the design reasons for including events as a system instead of having a few magic properties? Are callback properties an anti-pattern or is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: I mean, communication is significantly easier to configure with events because Vue does include an event-based system. You don't have to worry about whether or not a component is actually listening to that event (in a callback based notification system, you have to handle the callback potentially not existing by way of either a default callback or a null-check). Plus, it's easier to figure out what are events and props on a Vue component (`@` vs `:`) and I think readability is a very clear design concern of Vue.js, as it is, IMO the most readable modern JS UI framework out there currently.

Comment: Not really, it's mostly just an opinion haha. Any answer to this would most likely be an opinion unless it came from Evan You himself, and I don't think anyone wants to risk the downvotes.